# How find which process generate max read/write disk operation

Tags: unix, io, debian

Cloud server begin generate big disk read/write operation. I want find some script who generate top file with process(process name | TOTAL |  READ  | WRITE )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) to see the reads and writes of each process using a `top` like interface.

Another way is to look at the `/proc/[PID]/io` files.

Example:

```
$ cat /proc/1944/io
read_bytes: 17961091072
write_bytes: 8192000
cancelled_write_bytes: 32768
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a monitor much like top available: [Iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).

Since you're using Debian Linux, you can simply retrieve it via APT:

> apt-get install iotop

Done.

Comment: I already installed this script. But he generated realtime. I need demon who run 24h and generate file with statistic.

Comment: Hhm. Shoulda put this in your question, then. I guess, dogbane's answer should give you a hint on how to implement a demon like this.